# Convert this code to LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Sorry, Im just learning LINQ and am relatively new at it.

Is it possible to convert the following into LINQ?

```
foreach (DataRow gradeCount in GraceTable.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToDecimal(obtMarksRow["Percentage"]) >= 
        (Convert.ToDecimal(gradeCount["EXG_MARKS_ABOVE"])) &&
        (Convert.ToDecimal(obtMarksRow["Percentage"]) <= 
        Convert.ToDecimal(gradeCount["EXG_MARKS_BELOW"])))
    {
        string Grade = Convert.ToString(gradeCount["EXG_GRADE_NAME"]);
    }
}
```

**Edit :** sorry i missed  for each loop in ma query and obtMarksRow comes from one more loop which is outside this

I wrote the query like this

```
     var gradeValue = from DataRow gradeRow in GraceTable.Rows
                                 let marksAbove = gradeRow.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_ABOVE") 
                                 let marksBelow = gradeRow.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_BELOW")
                                 where obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") >= marksAbove && obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") <= marksBelow
                                 select gradeRow.Field<string>("EXG_GRADE_NAME");
```

but i am getting the value (gradeValue.ToString() ) as "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.String]"

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Yes it's possible but why do you want to convert it?

Comment: I don't see a collection here. Linq is for querying any collection implementing IEnumerable.

Comment: LINQ is for querying enumerable types. This is just a single If statement. Unless this is in the context of a loop that iterates with obtMarksRow (in which case you need to give more code), this isn't relevant to linq.

Comment: You should convert your code to not use `Convert` for no reason.

Comment: @Nithesh Hebri: I wrote a response to your edit.

Comment: @ StriplingWarrior  i tried , but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. As the commenters point out, LINQ is for querying collections of things. You don't appear to have a collection here: just an `if` statement and an assignment.

Furthermore, be careful about trying to convert things to LINQ unnecessarily. As you start to understand LINQ better, you'll find yourself naturally using it for a variety of purposes. But starting off with the assumption that code will be better with LINQ is probably a fallacy.

#### Edit

As mentioned earlier, LINQ is about querying a collection for a set of results. If you only want one result, you can use `Single`, `First`, `SingleOrDefault`, or `FirstOrDefault` to get it out of the resulting collection.

```
 var gradeValues = from DataRow gradeRow in GraceTable.Rows
                             let marksAbove = gradeRow.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_ABOVE") 
                             let marksBelow = gradeRow.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_BELOW")
                             where obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") >= marksAbove && obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") <= marksBelow
                             select gradeRow.Field<string>("EXG_GRADE_NAME");

var firstGradeValue = gradeValues.First(); // will throw exception if there were no matches.
Console.WriteLine(firstGradeValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var grades = from r in GraceTables.Rows
             where obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") >= 
                     r.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_ABOVE") && 
                   obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") <= 
                     r.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_BELOW")
             select r.Field<string>("EXG_GRADE_NAME");
```

Comment: I tried this ,but i am getting the value  as "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.String]"

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Linq per se but you should use the DatasetExtensions, brought in alongside linq, to get your columns from the DataRow in a type safe way without the need to convert them, i.e.

```
if (obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") >= (Convert.ToDecimal(gradeCount["EXG_MARKS_ABOVE"])) && etc...
```